# EasyVR serial connection C linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm working on an EasyVR device (voice recognition system) and trying to communicate with my computer using a serial connection. If I send a `b` I'm supposed to receive an `o`.

I wrote a C program to do this and I'm able to send a `b`, but the `read` function  is not working.
I saw with an oscilloscope that I'm sending the good caracter and I'm receiving an `o` too.
I also tested with gtkterm and my EasyVR worked well.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{

int port_serie;
struct termios options;
int reception=1;
/*char buffer[10];*/ char buffer ='m';
char data = 'b'; //message que tu veux envoyer


port_serie = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);//lecture et ecriture | pas controlling terminal | ne pas attendre DCD

//cas d'erreur d'ouverture
if(port_serie < 0)
{
    perror("Erreur d'ouverture du port serie");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

else
{
    printf("Port serie numero %d bien ouvert. \n", port_serie);

    //chargement des données
    tcgetattr(port_serie, &options);
    //9600 bauds
    cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD );//programme propriétaire du port
    //structure en 8N1 !!
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; //pas de parité
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // 1 bit de stop
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; //option a 0
    options.c_cflag |= CS8; //8 bits
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;// pas de flow de controle
    tcsetattr(port_serie, TCSANOW, &options); //enregistrement des valeurs de configuration
    printf("Configuration OK strcuture en 8N1 !. \n");
    //while(buffer !='o'){
        // Envoie de donnees.
        printf("Envoie des donnees en cours ... \n");
        if (write(port_serie,&data, 1) < 0){perror("ERROR\n");}
        printf("Envoie Termine. \n");

        // Lecture des donnees.
        printf("Lecture des donnees en cours ... \n");
        fcntl(port_serie,F_SETFL,1);//mode bloquant pour la fonction read() si aucun caractere dispo, programme attend
        reception=read(port_serie,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        printf("message recu : %c\n",buffer);

        if (reception == -1){
        printf("Erreur lecture port serie\n");

        printf("Reception finie.\n" );sleep(1);
 //}

}

close(port_serie);//fermeture du port serie

return 0;
}
```

code edited : 01/22  10:50am

Comment: Define _`Not Working`_

Comment: Couple of points. You send 1 character and expect 1 character back, but are not terminating the `buffer` where you treat the reply as a string. Next, if you have not enabled blocking mode, remember that at 9600 baud it will take at least 2 milliseconds to receive a reply, so on the call to `read()` you might get 0 characters waiting.

Comment: Your `read(...,&buffer,...)` statement has pointer to a pointer for the second argument, but it should be just a pointer, i.e. `read(..., buffer,...)`.  And as @WeatherVane pointed out, once that character is stored in the correct buffer (or the `read()` simply returns), the code to print it is flawed.  Overall your program should be checking the return values from all syscalls, and during compile you should enable all warnings to catch issues like that bad `read()` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.
I modified my code, like it was before I try a lot of thing. When I enable blocking mode the program stay in read mode.

Comment: Your code still has a serious problem/deficiency in properly checking the return codes from syscalls.   The read call will block when only one alpha character is received without any line termination, since the serial port is configured for canonical mode.